# How can I check if a variable is contains only letters

Tags: bash

I tried to check the following case:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="abc"

if [[ "${line}" != [a-z] ]]; then
   echo INVALID
fi
```

And I get `INVALID` as output. But why?
It's no check if `$line` contains only a characters in the range [a-z] ?

Answer (score 6):

Use the regular expression matching operator `=~`:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="abc"

if [[ "${line}" =~ [^a-zA-Z] ]]; then
   echo INVALID
fi
```

Comment: Edited to accept capital letters and reject lines like abc123.

Comment: Note that `=~` is a non-portable bashism.

Answer (score 2):

Works in any Bourne shell and wastes no pipes/forks:

```
case $var in
   ("")       echo "empty";;
   (*[!a-z]*) echo "contains a non-alphabetic";;
   (*)        echo "just alphabetics";;
esac
```

Use `[!a-zA-Z]` if you want to allow upper case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
line="abc"
if  echo "$line" | grep -i -q '^[a-z]*$'
then
        echo "MATCHED."
else
        echo "NOT-MATCHED."
fi
```

Comment: You don’t need to specify the upper- _and_ lowercase ranges in the regular expression pattern because you’ve already specified that matching be case-insensitive with the `-i` flag.

Comment: @CJK, sure cool, thanks for letting know, edited now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matches are anchored to the beginning and end of the string, so your code checks if `$line` is not a *single* lowercase character. You want to match an arbitrary *sequence* of lowercase characters, which you can do using extended patterns:

```
if [[ $line != @([a-z]) ]]; then
```

or using the regular-expression operator:

```
if ! [[ $line =~ ^[a-z]+$ ]]; then  # there is no negative regex operator like Perl's !~
```

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because `!=` means "not equal", thats why.  You tell bash to compare `abc` with `[a-z]`.  They are not equal.

Try `echo $line | grep -i -q -x '[a-z]*'`.

The flag -i makes grep case insensitive.
The flag -x means match the whole line.
The flag -q means print nothing to stdout, just return 1 or 0.

Comment: Without quotes, bash tries to expand file names with `[a-z]*`.